# I need a regular expression that only accepts text characters with spaces allowed

Tags: regex, validation

i have a textbox in my asp page that i need to validate to allow user to input only text characters from A-Z , a-z... but with **spaces allowed** between words..

i have tried the following but it doesn't work(doesn't allow spaces)::

```
^[a-zA-Z]*$
```

can i change it to make it allow spaces???

Comment: You can allow spaces by adding the spaces in the character class. What have you tried?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak how can i do that??

Comment: Do you need to reject multiple consecutive spaces, leading spaces or trailing spaces as well?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this, for regular expression

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add the RegEx character \s to your regular expression, allowing spaces, whitespace and line breaks:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Or, like the other posters said, use a space, to only allow spaces:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Comment: `\s` will add all whitespace, not just the spaces.

Comment: Great point, looks like it adds tabs and line breaks. http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 3):

Just add a space between the brackets.

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the space to the character class:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

(only spaces) or

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

(all whitespace - spaces, tabs, newlines...)

Comment: Pick this one to include tabs and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to allow spaces:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following to allow small and capital letters

```
/(^[a-z ]+$)/i
```

i -> Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

Comment: This should be added as a comment to the existing answer as it simply adds case ignore option, not a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

takes into account Turkish letters as well.

```
export const letterRegexFormat = /^[a-zA-ZöçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-ZöçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ, ])*$/;
```